# Gradle + PlayFramework: Cannot resolve sources dependency

Tags: gradle, playframework, dependency-management

I'm using the new Play Framework support in Gradle 2.7.

Ironically, Play 2.3.x explicitly depends on `org.scala-sbt:io:0.13.8`.

Gradle is able to resolve the JAR (not the sources, just the classes) from typesafe's repository if I add

`model {
    components {
      play {
        platform play: "2.3.7", scala: "2.10", java: "1.7"
      }
    }
 }
 repositories {
    maven {
      name "typesafe-maven-release"
      url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases"
    }
    ivy {
      name "typesafe-ivy-release"
      url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"
      layout "ivy"
    }
 } 
 dependencies {
    play group: "org.scala-sbt", name: "io", version: "0.13.8", classifier: "jar", configuration: "compile"
 }`

however it seems that it cannot resolve the `io-sources.jar`. I get this:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':runPlayBinary'.

  > Could not find io-sources.jar (org.scala-sbt:io:0.13.8).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.8/srcs/io.jar

I actually don't care about these sources, I just want to avoid this runtime exception when running `gradlew runPlay`

> Execution exception
>   [RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/Path$]

Any advice? I can't seem to figure out how to exclude or resolve the sources dependency.

Comment: I've answered on the Gradle Forum: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-2-7-play-cannot-resolve-sources-dependency/11707

Comment: Found a comment about Typesafe Ivy repo: https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li-sbt-plugin/blob/de19700211923d76acdccfd40610884a4e689717/build.gradle#L77-L82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind Gradle dev answered my question on the [Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-2-7-play-cannot-resolve-sources-dependency/11707)

TL;DR - Gradle/Play bug specific to 2.3.7 that can be resolved by using

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml"
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/jars/[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, upgrading to Play 2.3.9 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same RuntimeException (NoClassDefFound sbt/Path$) with Play 2.4 and Gradle 2.7. In my case the root problem was to not define all repositories correctly (didn't include typesafe-ivy -> sbt-io was not resolved -> thought i need to state sbt-io-dependency -> wrong sbt-io led to mentioned Exception...).

I would advise you to add jcenter() as repository, remove the explicit dependency on sbt and state the play version in your build.gradle. As an example my working gradle.build:

```
plugins {
 id 'play'
}
dependencies {
 repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven {
    name "typesafe-maven-release"
    url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases"
  }
  ivy {
    name "typesafe-ivy-release"
    url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"
    layout "ivy"
  }
 }
 play 'com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc_2.11:2.4.3'
 [...other dependencies - but not "org.scala-sbt"!]
}

model {
 components {
  play {
    platform play: '2.4.3', scala: '2.11'
    injectedRoutesGenerator = true
  }
 }
}
```

In your case the last part should be:

```
model {
 components {
  play {
    platform play: '2.3.7', scala: '2.10'
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Adding jcenter() and variations of excluding "org.scala-sbt" haven't changed things for the better, I'm afraid. When you say "remove the explicit dependency", do you exclude sbt across the whole play configuration or another way?

Comment: I've updated the suggestion to make clear that I just don't bother myself with importing "org.scala-sbt" in my build file.